# Try to work my VUE PWA app offline (no internet) without using firebase database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm migrating the Vuejs application (firestore to mongodb) previously my app using the firstore database and its offline functionality to keep up to date the database while user is offline, but now I'm not using the firestore, instead I'm using the NodeJS server and MongoDB as database.

So how I can achieve the same offline functionality with this stack (Vuejs + Nodejs + MongoDB) to perform my app well without internet connection and as soon as possible use get online update the database.

Comment: It's a very vague question.  What about Node + MongoDB do you need technical help with?  Logically, the app will work the same as it did with firebase, just instead of making a request for data from firestore it makes a request to your NodeJS server.  Your node server fetches the data from MongoDB and returns it as a response.  Without a more specific question that's as specific as I can answer.

Comment: Google has a dedicated thing called Workbox which can help you achieve Web Workers easily and get your data offline stored on your device with a fake loopback: https://web.dev/learn/pwa/workbox/

Comment: Thanks youduh for your response. Actually everything is fine with mongodb but how I achieve the offline functionality in my vue app.

example
user is offline and create new company in my app, so when user get online I need to create that company into the mongodb so how can I make that request after user online.

does it make sense ?

Comment: By using a service worker network catcher and actually sending that one to your backend. Until you're back live on the Internet, keep it locally on your user's device.

Comment: Thanks Kissu, there is any vuejs library I should use for that purpose along with service worker or just service worker.

Comment: You can use a wrapper for sure: https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/ Here is the one using Vite but you can also find one using Webpack of course.